# C# как считать output процесса?

Tags: c#, строки, консоль, потоки-данных, процесс

В отдельном процессе открывается консоль, в которую передаётся команда. Хочется получить результат команды, который вместо вывода в консоль, должен сохраниться в переменной типа **string** и вернуться вызывающему методу. Вот код, который не работает:

```
internal class ConsoleBuilder
{
    private static int lineCount = 0;
    private static StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    internal static void Execute(string command, ref Process proc, out string outputText, out string outputError)
    {
        outputText = string.Empty;
        outputError = string.Empty;
        proc = new Process();

        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", command);
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                lineCount++;
                output.Append("\n[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
            }
        });

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

        outputText = output.ToString();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string command = "echo I'm here!";
        string pathToCmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
        Process proc = null;
        string outputText = string.Empty;
        string outputError = string.Empty;

        ConsoleBuilder.Execute(command, ref proc, out outputText, out outputError);
        Console.WriteLine(outputText);
    }
}
```

Строка **outputText** возвращается пустая. Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно решал такую же проблему, нашел ответ на англоязычной версии сайта. Странно, что Вы его не нашли). Скорее всего, проблема заключается в том, что Вы не дожидаетесь окончания выполнения процесса. Вот код, который работает у меня.

```
public static string ExecuteExternal(string fileName, string args, int timeout) {
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

    using (Process process = new Process()) {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false)) {
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
                if (e.Data == null) {
                    outputWaitHandle.Set();
                } else {
                    log.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
                if (e.Data == null) {
                    errorWaitHandle.Set();
                } else {
                    log.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };

            process.Start();

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            if (timeout > 0) {
                if (process.WaitForExit(timeout) &&
                    outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout) &&
                    errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout)) {

                }
            } else {
                process.WaitForExit();
                outputWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                errorWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            }
        }
    }

    return log.ToString();
}
```

Comment: а если процесс бесконечный и я не могу ждать его окончания?

Comment: @neo, Для этого есть таймаут) В мой метод передается параметр timeout. Если его значение > 0, значит таймаут выставлен, в противном случае ждем окончания процесса. [Вот ссылка на первоисточник](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why/7608823#7608823)

Comment: Ну только таймаутов и не хватало, когда и так хендлер вызывается, когда нужно.

Answer (score 1):

> Строка outputText возвращается пустая. Подскажите, что не так?

<sub>Ну вот, я всё-таки посмотрел внимательнее код...</sub>

Проблема в том, что ты возвращаешь строку сразу, а коллбек вызывается асинхронно, т. е. уже после того, как строка возвращена.

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронно считывать не получилось. Зато сработало решение синхронного чтения, предложенное здесь: [Synchronous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753402/3844702).

```
internal class ConsoleBuilder
{
    private static int lineCount = 0;
    internal static StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    internal static string myStr = string.Empty;

    internal static void Execute(string command, ref Process process, out string outputText, out string outputError)
    {
        outputText = string.Empty;
        outputError = string.Empty;
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + command; // Note the /c command (*)
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        outputText = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        outputError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(outputError);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```vb
ChDir("D:\Некий Путь\bin")

Dim Info As New ProcessStartInfo With {
  .FileName = "cmd.exe",
  .Arguments = "/k ""D:\Некий Путь\bin\startup.bat""",
  .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
  .RedirectStandardError = True,
  .UseShellExecute = False,
  .CreateNoWindow = True}

Dim Prc As Process = Process.Start(Info)

Do
  Dim Line As String = Await Prc.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync()
  If Line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
  RtbStart1.Text += Line + vbCrLf
Loop
```

Comment: На основе http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6779052#p6779052

Comment: а есть код на C# всё-таки?

Comment: @neo, а что в этом непонятно?

Comment: а то, что нужно знать конкретные функции языка C# для того, чтобы осуществлять синхронное перенаправление вывода консоли. Зачем тут функции другого языка?

Comment: и раз уж вы говорите, что нужно читать синхронно, зачем тогда **Prc.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync()**?

Comment: @neo, функции платформы .net одинаковы во всех языках. `ChDir` меняется на `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, либо вообще убирается. С остальным никаких проблем быть не должно.

Comment: @neo, это не такой Async. Там же await. Я не говорю, что нужно читать синхронно. Я говорю, что не нужно использовать результат раньше, чем он получен.