# C# как передать управление родительскому процессу до окончания работы дочернего?

Tags: c#, события, потоки-данных, процесс, handlers

В приложении на C# в главном потоке создаётся процесс и запускается. Однако, главный поток замирает до тех пор, пока не завершится дочерний процесс. Дочерний процесс может работать долго и хотелось бы сразу возвращать управление главному потоку. Предусмотрена ли такая возможность средствами языка C#?

**P.S.:** находил информацию о том, что можно использовать Event Handlers, но они работают на завершение процесса.

Answer (score 3):

Без дополнительных телодвижений родительский процесс никогда не блокируется не ждет дочернего.

Найдите у себя строчку, которая блокирует родительский процесс - и удалите ее :)

**UPD** Если вам надо читать вывод дочернего процесса - то в простом случае достаточно разнести запуск и чтение по времени. Этот способ подразумевает, что о готовности данных становится известно из внешнего источника.

Иначе надо читать в отдельном потоке.

Ну или можно использовать асинхронные операции, как предложил Grundy в комментариях.

Comment: как она может выглядеть, например?

Comment: @neo, `Wait` - чего-нибудь, либо `Read`

Comment: @Grundy, есть такая строка: **string outputText = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();**

Comment: @neo, я думаю это именно она

Comment: @neo эта строчка (сюрприз!) записывает в строку весь вывод дочернего процесса. Как вообще вы представляете продолжение работы родительского процесса с незаполненной до конца строковой переменной? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я подозреваю в этом как раз и был вопрос :)

Comment: @Grundy, тут, безусловно, не поспоришь. Но фишка в том, что читать-то всё равно надо. Другой вопрос, как тогда читать, чтобы не блочилась главная треда?

Comment: @neo, возможно поможет [Process.BeginOutputReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @neo обновил ответ

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, с асинхронными операциями как-то не очень получилось((( пока научился только синхронно читать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512372/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-output-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: @neo вы опять пытаетесь усидеть на двух стульях сразу. Вы не можете магически продолжить программу сразу же - но чтобы в некоторой переменной уже оказался полный текст вывода

Comment: @neo Если вам надо чтобы родительский и дочерний процессы исполнялись одновременно - забудьте о том, что вывод дочернего процесса можно положить в переменную.

Comment: @neo Надо обрабатывать вывод дочернего процесса по мере его поступления.