# Перехват вывода CMD и Powershell в переменную string?

Tags: c#

Как сделать вывод результата команд CMD и Powershell не в консоль и не в текстовый файл, а сразу в переменную string?

Comment: ровно так же как в консоль или файл, просто замените код обработки вывода сторонней программы на запись в нужное вам место.

Comment: приведите пример пожалуйста. Ваше объяснение мне непонятно

Comment: Вопрос написан так, как будто вы уже нашли и посмотрели соответствующие примеры. Или это только для красоты? Перехват консольного вывода описан тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316, вам нужно изменить только обработчик события (он в примере один)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kUlRYAPyzw

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512387/178988

Comment: @Bulson спасибо за видео

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main()
    {
        //cmd
        Process processCMD = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                //нужно использовать кодировку иначе будут кракозябры
                Arguments = "/c chcp 65001 & ipconfig",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle =  ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            }
        );
        string t1 = processCMD.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //PewerShell
        Process processPowerShell = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell",
                Arguments = "/command Get-Date",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            }
        );
        string t2 = processPowerShell.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
```